# dynamic column name in update statemnt python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I keep having this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='".
columnfield is dynamic var passed from another function.

my code is:

```
c.execute("UPDATE cases SET" +columnfield+"=%s WHERE id=%s",(thwart(gethash),thwart(caseid)))
```

Any idea where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need one space after word `SET`. That's all.

Now you create strange word `SETcolumname=`

Better create statement (before `execute()`) and print it to see how it looks like. Then you can also use it directly in MySQL. Database gives you better error message and you can test it in database till you get expected result.